# WinDBG Conditional Breakpoint on NtCreateFile

Tags: windbg

Debugging Windows 10 with WinDBG, I have attached to the OS through a COM tunnel.
I am in a running process and would like to break when it tries to open a specific file called "MyFile".
What I have done is add a breakpoint on ntdll!NtCreateFile and when it breaks I use the following command to check the filename:

```
dt _OBJECT_PROPERTIES @r8
```

Which gives me :

```
+ 0x10 ObjectName             : 0xADDRESS_OF_STRING C:/Folder/NotMyFile
```

The problem being that this function is called quite a lot of times so my debugging is too slow. Is there a way I can automate this using the conditional breakpoint of WinDBG?

Comment: try `bp XXXXXX "j ($scmp($r8+0x10,'C:/Folder/NotMyFile')==0) ' '; 'gc' "` replace XXXXX with the address of `NtCreateFile`

Comment: @EdChum: NtCreateFile is a synonym for an address

Comment: @EdChum Is there a way to check if "MyFile" is in the string rather than just straight equals?

Comment: use `$spat` for pattern matching : `bp XXXXXX "j ($spat($r8+0x10,'C:/Folder/NotMyFile')==0) ' '; 'gc' "` see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-a-conditional-breakpoint)

Answer (score 2):

!process 0 0 YourProcessName

```
Example 

kd> !process 0 0 calc.exe
PROCESS 85c9ed40  SessionId: 1  Cid: 0ae8    Peb: 7ffdd000  ParentCid: 075c
    DirBase: 7e248560  ObjectTable: e44da728  HandleCount:  71.
    Image: calc.exe
```

grab the EPROCESS Address from this

and set a process specific breakpoint like

```
bp /p 85c9ed40 nt!NtCreateFile
```

this should drastically cutdown the hits and would only break when NtCreateFile is being invoked under your process

go for conditionals only if your process opens many files or opens this specific several times otherwise you wont need any conditionals

Comment: I am trying to debug svchost and the process seems to do quite a lot of call to NtCreateFile, your answer helped but I still am facing too many calls